Am I able to render an image of my object after rendering an animation of it?
I recently rendered a simple animation of my object and it turned out well.  I am now trying to render detailed images of my object in .png format, but am unable to download them/export them.  I created a new folder and selected it in my render output settings, but once the render is complete, it doesn't appear in my folder.  I'm in cycles, my playback scroller is at the 0 frame, and I just want to render 1 frame at 350 samples.
Here's my render output settings, would anyone mind letting me know if I have something clicked/not clicked that should or should not be?  I tried clicking and un-clicking cache result to no effect.

Rendering images does not automatically save them. You have to save them manually from the render result in the Image Editor. Rendering an animation as image sequence will automatically save the images so that they do not have to be kept all together in memory while rendering.

Oh...duh thanks
